# summing Float32Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible and if yes how?

I want to sume multiple float32Arrays into one float32array.

I know this sounds as a stupid question but it turnes out doing this mannually takes quit some time.

Is it possible to make it faster than this?

recBuffers is an array of float32Array buffers with a length of approx 6594048

```
function mergeBuffers(recBuffers, recLength){

  var result = new Float32Array(recLength);
  var offset = 0

  for (var i=0; i<recBuffers.length; i++){  
      for (var j=0; j<recBuffers[i].length; j++){
        result[j] += recBuffers[i][j];
      } 
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you iterate on their lengths ? Maybe you should detail your question.

Comment: because i can't acces the members...

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke Please read [What Have You Tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and the [stack overflow faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Float32Array) :

> Once established, you can reference elements in the array using the
>   object's methods, or using standard array index syntax (that is, using
>   bracket notation).

Given two float32Arrays `a` and `b`, you can do this :

```
var c = new Float32Array(Math.min(a.length, b.length));
for (var i=c.length; i-->0;) c[i] = a[i]+b[i];
```